# Is there a way to count the number of nodes given that a sibling node condition is true?

Tags: xpath, count, siblings

I am trying to count the number of nodes that exist given a condition in a sibling node is met.

I have tried several XPath combinations, but I'm not sure it's possible.

```
<ab:Person>
    <ab:Gender ab:Descriptor="Girl">
    </ab:Gender>
    <ab:body>
        <ab:finger>1</ab:finger>
    </ab:body>
    <ab:body>
        <ab:finger>2</ab:finger>
    </ab:body>
    <ab:body>
        <ab:finger>3</ab:finger>
    </ab:body>
</ab:Person>

<ab:Person>
    <ab:Gender ab:Descriptor="Boy">
    </ab:Gender>
    <ab:body>
        <ab:finger>4</ab:finger>
    </ab:body>
    <ab:body>
        <ab:finger>5</ab:finger>
    </ab:body>
</ab:Person>
```

I want to count the number of  nodes for each Gender -- i.e. count(ab:finger, given that ab:Person/ab:Gender ab:Descriptor="Boy") and (ab:finger, given that ab:Person/ab:Gender ab:Descriptor="Girl").

My desired output for the two xpath functions above would be 2 and 3...as the number of ab:finger nodes that exist for "Boy" is 2, and "Girl" is 3.

Please let me know if the question doesn't make sense - I can elaborate further!

Comment: Do note that `ab:finger` are not `ab:Gender` 's siblings. Those `ab:body` are. Also, that means that they have the same parent `ab:Person`. So, a more "forward" expression could be: `count(/*/ab:Person[ab:Gender/@ab:Descriptor = 'Boy']/ab:body/ab:finger)`

Answer (score 0):

If there were a variable number of genders then this would become a grouping problem. But if there are only two, then it's very simple:

```
count(ab:Person[ab:Gender/@ab:Descriptor="Boy"]/ab:body/ab:finger)

count(ab:Person[ab:Gender/@ab:Descriptor="Girl"]/ab:body/ab:finger)
```